# Unable to load reactjs components if I visit specific page in my website without visiting my home page - (Node + MongoDB + express + ReactJs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using ReactJS as frontend and Nodejs as backend. If I visit localhost:3000, I get all the required data and react components. However if I directly visit localhost:3000/component/componentId,I am only able to fetch data from node js and unable to render React components. Need help.

My app.js

```
////some code
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  })
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App is running on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log("------------------------------------------------")
});
```

I have specified routes in React as

```
////some code
<Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
<Route path="/blogs" exact component={BlogList} />
<Route path="/blogs/:blogId" exact component={Blog} />
////some code
```

Comment: any error message or console.logs something etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a middle type ?

```
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  })
```